# Where is low level code of Javascript standard built-in objects?

Tags: javascript, built-in, polyfills

I'm looking for the way to get low level code of javascript built-in function.
For example, there is an polyfill(I want like this form and I call this low level code in my way) in mdn site of 'Array.prototype.indexOf()'
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

And I get to understand that it is kinda low level code of built-in method.
Here is my question, where can I see the code to look inside of method of 'String.prototype.toLowerCase()'?

Comment: Depends on the implementation. One is here: https://github.com/v8/v8

Comment: Note that it won't be written in javascript...

Comment: For Google Chrome and current version of Edge you can find the implementation of indexOf here: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/ee74e718339223345b42935e9f4cbc7be208e557/src/runtime/runtime-array.cc#L330

Comment: For Safari you can find the implementation of indexOf here: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/9412129f9315eb2de1f7b58bdd6ac53243dcd255/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArrayPrototype.cpp#L1359 but note that it is a wrapper to the real implementation. In the same file search for the `fastIndexOf` function

Comment: For Firefox I can't link to it directly but you can download the source of Spidermonkey from Mozilla's FTP servers and look for it yourself: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/78.1.0esr/source/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on your javascript implementation.

For V8, [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/src/strings/string-case.cc) is the guts of toLowerCase (and toUpperCase)

Low level functions (such as these) are generally written in whatever language the javascript engine is written in - that's why they're so fast. So don't go in expecting something that's easy to read for the average javascript-only developer :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for probably doesn't exist but I'll do my best do help you out.

The low level function are dependent on which **Engine** you are using.
A few examples are:

- **[V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine))** — open source, developed by Google, written in C++
- **[Rhino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine))** — managed by the Mozilla Foundation, open source, developed entirely in Java
- **[SpiderMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey)** — the first JavaScript engine, which back in the days powered Netscape Navigator, and today powers Firefox
- **[JavaScriptCore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore)** — open source, marketed as Nitro and developed by Apple for Safari

I assume you are looking for the function to understand what they are doing. If this is the case and you don't understand the languages that the engines are written it might be an idea to look at the `polyfill` implementation of those functions. Those **are** written in javascript and might help you understand them if that's what you are looking for.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is defined by a standard, with many major implementations.

The definition for that method and others can be found in the [TC39 website](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.indexof). It is only defined algorithmically, not in actual code.

That being said, for the open-source implementations, you can actually look at the source code for those implementations, though they will probably be in some other language, such as C++.

The major current open-source implementations of JavaScript are [Google's V8](https://v8.dev/), [Apple's WebKit](https://webkit.org/) and [Mozilla's SpiderMonkey](https://spidermonkey.dev/).

Comment: Also add JavaScriptCore which is part of Webkit. While not as popular as V8 it is widely used because it is the only javascript engine approved for iOS so it is used by Google Chrome for iOS, Brave for iOS, a lot of hybrid mobile applications such as banking apps etc: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/main/Source/JavaScriptCore. It is certainly more widely used than SpiderMonkey

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was open-source, I thought JSC was specifically a proprietary iOS thing.